# Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' from your host to server at localhost:3306: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61)

Tags: mysql, macos

Am getting the following message error when I try to open my connections in mysql workbench. Am using Mysql workbench 6.3 (64 -bits) on Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.5

The error message:

> Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' from your host to
>   server at localhost:3306: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1'
>   (61)
>
> Please:
>
> 1. Check that mysql is running on server localhost
> 2. Check that mysql is running on port 3306 (note: 3306 is the default, but this can be changed)
> 3. Check the root has rights to connect to localhost from your address (mysql rights define what clients can connect to the server and from which machines)
> 4. Make sure you are both providing a password if needed and using the correct password for localhost connecting from the host address you're connecting from

Help would be much appreciated.

Thank you,

Peter

Comment: How many of those four suggestions did you chase down?

Comment: there is 1 box in question, your dev box, that has mysql daemon running. Right ?